# On compact Kahler manifold, Lie derivative of Killing vector field commutes with $dd^c$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, lie-derivative

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a compact Kahler manifold, $X$ a Killing vector field, $f \in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}). $ I would like to show that:
$L_X(dd^cf) = dd^cL_Xf$.

If I write it out locally, $X = X^i \partial_{z_i}$, $X^i$ are pluriharmonic functions. Then locally, we have:

$L_X(dd^cf) = (f_{ki\bar{j}} X^i + f_{i\bar{j}} X^i_k) \space dz_k \wedge \bar{dz_j}$

On the other hand, we have:

$dd^cL_Xf = (f_iX^i_{k\bar{j}}  + f_{ik}X^i_{\bar{j}}  +  f_{ki\bar{j}}X^i+f_{i\bar{j}}X^i_k)    \space dz_k \wedge \bar{dz_j} 
= (f_{ik}X^i_{\bar{j}}  +  f_{ki\bar{j}}X^i+f_{i\bar{j}}X^i_k)    \space dz_k \wedge \bar{dz_j}$

because $X^i$ pluriharmonic so $dd^c X^i = 0$ and $X^i_{k\bar{j}} = 0$.

The only difference between the 2 expressions is the term $f_{ik}X^i_{\bar{j}}$.

Comment: What is a real holomorphic vector field? How is this a well-defined notion independent of holomorphic chart?

Comment: I will edit the post: I actually only care about Killing vector field, which happens to be real holomorphic on a compact Kahler manifold. I use the definition from here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133700/every-real-holomorphic-hamiltonian-vector-field-on-a-k%C3%A4hler-manifold-is-killing?

Comment: Also, a vector field $X$ is real holomorphic if $X - iJX$ is holomorphic. I am using the definition from this note https://moroianu.perso.math.cnrs.fr/tex/kg.pdf

Comment: Instead of looking at the Lie derivative, you might want to consider the flow of $X$ and the pull-back of $dd{cf$ along this flow.

Comment: Could you write this into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a *real holomorphic* vector field on $M$, i.e. a smooth section of the (real) tangent bundle of $M$ such that $\mathcal{L}_XJ=0$. Every Killing vector field on a compact Kähler manifold has this property, see for example Theorem 4.81 in [Ballmann's notes](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/kaehler0609.pdf) (note that he calls these vector fields *automorphic*, rather than real holomorphic).

We can show something more than your claim, namely that for any $p$-form $\alpha$ on $M$, one has $\mathcal{L}_X\mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^c\alpha=\mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^c\mathcal{L}_X\alpha$. It is not necessary to assume that $M$ is Kähler. To do this, we only need three ingredients:

1. if $\Phi_t$ is the flow of $X$, then for any tensor field $V$ on $M$ the Lie derivative is defined as $\mathcal{L}_XV=\partial_{t=0}\Phi_t^*V$;
2. the exterior derivative is *natural*, i.e. for any diffeomorphism $\Phi$ and any $p$-form $\alpha$ one has $\Phi^*(\mathrm{d}\alpha)=\mathrm{d}(\Phi^*\alpha)$;
3. a vector field is real holomorphic if and only if its flow is made of biholomorphisms of $M$.

With these in place, we can then proceed as follows, where $\Phi_t$ is the flow of $X$. First, by property $1$ we have
$$\mathcal{L}_X\mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^c\alpha=\partial_{t=0}\Phi_t^*\left(\mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^c\alpha\right)=\partial_{t=0}\Phi_t^*\left(\mathrm{d}(J^{-1}\mathrm{d}(J\alpha)\right).$$
Now, using $2$ a couple of times we get
$$\Phi_t^*\left(\mathrm{d}(J^{-1}\mathrm{d}(J\alpha)\right)=d\left((\Phi_t^*J^{-1})d\left((\Phi_t^*J)(\Phi_t^*\alpha)\right)\right)$$
but by $3$ we know $\Phi_t^*J=J$ (and $\Phi_t^*J^{-1}=J$), so putting everything together
$$\mathcal{L}_X\mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^c\alpha=\partial_{t=0}\left(\mathrm{d}(J^{-1}\mathrm{d}(J(\Phi_t^*\alpha))\right)=\partial_{t=0}\left(\mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^c(\Phi_t^*\alpha)\right)=\mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^c\mathcal{L}_X\alpha.$$

So we just need to show the three things above. $1$ and $2$ are found in any differential geometry book, and $3$ is a consequence of $1$ and the definition of real holomorphic vector field. Let me know if you need help to show this, but I think it would be a good exercise to go through on your own.